# Display image from a list(column-hyperlink/image) using REST Api

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, sharepoint-rest-api, image

In my SharePoint Online site, I need to display images from a list on a page using REST API/jQuery.

The images in the list are stored in hyperlink/picture column in the list.

Can someone suggest me how to display image on a SharePoint page?
Card view:
[image: Card view]

Comment: Are you using Modern pages or classic pages?

Comment: classic pages only.

Comment: Are you able to use content editor/script editor in your site?

Answer (score 1):

Try using code something like below:

```
<div id='ImgContainerDiv'> </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfowebroot.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/items?$select=ID,Title,samplelogo",
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json; odata=verbose'
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var listData = data.d.results;
            if (listData && listData.length) {
                for (var i = 0; i < listData.length; i++) {
                    if(listData[i].samplelogo) {
                        $('#ImgContainerDiv').append('<img src="' + listData[i].samplelogo.Url + '"/>');
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Where `samplelogo` is [internal name](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/) of your hyperlink/picture column.

Comment: Have you tried this? were you able to get the picture column from sharepoint list using REST API?

Comment: should we add 'ImgContainerDiv' as id to html element in html file?
Actually, we have js file and html file diff in our project...we'll link the js file to html file. Sorry, am new to SharePoint, so kindly help me out if I missing anything

Comment: Yes, check updated answer. div is added in html with ID. This code is adding all items images in one div. you can change it according to your need.

Comment: am getting an error at 'Url' in this line  $('#ImgContainerDiv').append('<img src="' + listData[i].ImageCol.Url + '"/>');
Can you please tell me where am going wrong?

Comment: What is the error message/text? What is the internal name of your hyperlink/picture column? Is it required field?

Comment: The error message is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Url' of null"..but it is going inside success function, instead of image, 'undefined' is getting displayed.
Internal column is samplelogo, it is not a required field.

Comment: I have updated the code in my answer. please try and let me know if this works or not. As this is not a required field. some of the list items has blank value in your "samplelogo" column. that is what causing this error.

Comment: Unfortunately, the result is unchanged, as you said I've not left samplelogo column blank. It has some image.

Comment: Can you please check again using updated code? Select the column(samplelogo) in `$select` in REST URL, then inside `for` loop and `if` condition to insure that the `listData[i].samplelogo` is not null and `listData[i].samplelogo.Url` has value in it.

Comment: Also, please add the code you are using and the screenshot of error you are getting to your question. that will be helpful to answer your question easily.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103607/discussion-between-monika-kandregula-and-ganesh-sanap).