# Display Image from a SharePoint list using JavaScript Rest Api

Tags: sharepoint-server

On my sharepoint site, I have a list that has images stored in a hyperlink/images column that i need to display. I have been trying to apply the two following questions to my use case, & I cannot seem to get it to work properly because I want the image to change with the query string parameter.
I am able to get the correct image url from the list, but I want to be able to use that url in the image tag to display the image. I have some working code below, where the image variable has the image url, please tell me what I am doing wrong here? Thank you in advance!

[Display image from a list(column-hyperlink/image) using REST Api](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/274287/display-image-from-a-listcolumn-hyperlink-image-using-rest-api)

[How to retrieve image column from SharePoint List using REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/159793/how-to-retrieve-image-column-from-sharepoint-list-using-rest-api#)

working code:

````
<html lang="en"
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
    <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            JSRequest.EnsureSetup();
            var itemId = JSRequest.QueryString["PAM"];
            var urlFilter = "my_site/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ImageTest')/items?$filter=ID eq "+itemId;
            console.log(urlFilter);
            $.ajax({
                url:urlFilter,
                headers:{
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log('Success');
            var parser, xmlDoc;

            var text = data.children[0].outerHTML;
            console.log(text);
            parser = new DOMParser();
            xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");
            console.log(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('entry')[0].getElementsByTagName('content')[0].getElementsByTagName('m:properties')[0].getElementsByTagName('d:Images')[0]);
            var image= xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('entry')[0].getElementsByTagName('content')[0].getElementsByTagName('m:properties')[0].getElementsByTagName('d:Images')[0].getElementsByTagName('d:Url')[0];

            console.log(image);
              
                 $("#Image").append('<img src="' + image + '"/>');
                  },

                error: function (data) {
                    alert("Got an error dude... " + data);
                },       
            }); 
        });    
         
    </script>
<div id = "Image" class=""> </div>
<div>
<img src= "image" alt="none" width="500" height="333">
</div>

    </body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved my own question.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
    <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            JSRequest.EnsureSetup();
            var itemId = JSRequest.QueryString["PAM"];
            var urlFilter = "my_site/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ImageTest')/items?$filter=ID eq "+itemId;
            console.log(urlFilter);
            $.ajax({
                url:urlFilter,
                headers:{
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log('Success');
            var parser, xmlDoc;

            var text = data.children[0].outerHTML;
            console.log(text);
            parser = new DOMParser();
            xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");
            console.log(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('entry')[0].getElementsByTagName('content')[0].getElementsByTagName('m:properties')[0].getElementsByTagName('d:Images')[0]);
            var image= xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('entry')[0].getElementsByTagName('content')[0].getElementsByTagName('m:properties')[0].getElementsByTagName('d:Images')[0].getElementsByTagName('d:Url')[0].textContent;

            console.log(image);
        var display = '<img src="' + image + '"' + 'width="400"' + 'height="500">';

            $('#Image').html(display);
                  },

                error: function (data) {
                    alert("Got an error dude... " + data);
                },       
            }); 
        });    
         
    </script>
<div id = "Image" class=""> </div>

    </body>
</html>
```